# Replace first n elements in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the first `n` elements of a column in my data frame with another pd.series I have saved. So as an example,

```
        category   price    store  testscore
0       Cleaning   11.42  Walmart        NaN
1       Cleaning   23.50      Dia        NaN
2  Entertainment   19.99  Walmart        NaN
3  Entertainment   15.95     Fnac        NaN
4           Tech   55.75      Dia        NaN
5           Tech  111.55  Walmart        NaN
```

Here I would want to replace the first three NaNs in testscore with a new set of strings.

Imagine I have a variable:

`cats = pd.Series(df['category'][0:2])`

So can I place this in the testscore column...

```
        category   price    store      testscore
0       Cleaning   11.42  Walmart       Cleaning
1       Cleaning   23.50      Dia       Cleaning
2  Entertainment   19.99  Walmart  Entertainment
3  Entertainment   15.95     Fnac            NaN
4           Tech   55.75      Dia            NaN
5           Tech  111.55  Walmart            NaN
```

But whenever I try to do this it won't work.

Code to create this fake dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['Cleaning', 'Cleaning', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Tech', 'Tech'],
                        'store': ['Walmart', 'Dia', 'Walmart', 'Fnac', 'Dia','Walmart'],
                        'price':[11.42, 23.50, 19.99, 15.95, 55.75, 111.55],
                        'testscore': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['Cleaning', 'Cleaning', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Tech', 'Tech'],
                        'store': ['Walmart', 'Dia', 'Walmart', 'Fnac', 'Dia','Walmart'],
                        'price':[11.42, 23.50, 19.99, 15.95, 55.75, 111.55],
                        'testscore': ['Cleaning', 'Cleaning', 'Entertainment', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

print(df2)
```

Comment: "whenever I try to do this it won't work." what is the error or result you get?

Comment: @Evan I don't get an error. It just won't impute the elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['Cleaning', 'Cleaning', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Tech', 'Tech'],
                        'store': ['Walmart', 'Dia', 'Walmart', 'Fnac', 'Dia','Walmart'],
                        'price':[11.42, 23.50, 19.99, 15.95, 55.75, 111.55],
                        'testscore': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})


cats = pd.Series(df['category'][:3]) # 3 elements

df.loc[:3,'testscore'] = cats # Assign first 3

print(df)
```

And you get:

```
        category   price    store      testscore
0       Cleaning   11.42  Walmart       Cleaning
1       Cleaning   23.50      Dia       Cleaning
2  Entertainment   19.99  Walmart  Entertainment
3  Entertainment   15.95     Fnac            NaN
4           Tech   55.75      Dia            NaN
5           Tech  111.55  Walmart            NaN
```

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Comment: Did you copy my code? Do you have the latest panda version?

Comment: Important to note that `df.loc`-style slice-indexing is inclusive of the upper bound, unlike the `numpy`-style slicing that works with chained indexing, so, for example, `df['category'][1:5]` is equivalent to `df.loc[1:4,'category']` NOT `df.loc[1:5,'category']`

Answer (score 2):

Use `fillna` with parameter `limit`:

```
df['testscore'] = df.testscore.fillna(df.category, limit=3)
df
```

Output:

```
        category   price    store      testscore
0       Cleaning   11.42  Walmart       Cleaning
1       Cleaning   23.50      Dia       Cleaning
2  Entertainment   19.99  Walmart  Entertainment
3  Entertainment   15.95     Fnac            NaN
4           Tech   55.75      Dia            NaN
5           Tech  111.55  Walmart            NaN
```